# activatedRoute snapshot does not work in TS class constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am facing an issue in typeScript and angular 2.
My TS class looks following,

```
'import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blogdetail',
  templateUrl: './blogdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blogdetail.component.css']
})
export class BlogdetailComponent implements OnInit {

   blogId:any;
   title:any;

    constructor(private _activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
    //Does not work
     // this.blogId = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    //this.title= `This is blog detail for blogID:${this.blogId}`;

   }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.blogId = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.title= `This is blog detail for blogID:${this.blogId}`;
  }

}'
```

I have to get the rout param in ngOnit event. when I initially use the same code( to get the param) in TS class constructor, I get the blogId variable value as ***undefined*** .  As far as I understand the sequence of events, they are similar to the below image, 
![flow]https://i.stack.imgur.com/41fpe.png

Do we HAVE to get the activatedRoute snapshot values in ngOnIt always ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right. 
What's happening is that when your component is initiated for your view, your `constructor` is called. But since that time just the new instance is being created, the route is not activated due to which you don't get the route params.
On the other hand, when you're using it in OnInit, the route is activated and you get the params. 
Still, i would't consider this as the best approach as you should subscribe to the route params in your OnInit to look for the params like :

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.routeParamsSub = this.route.params.subscribe(routeParams => {
        this.blogId = routeParams['id']; 

       // do something else here
    });
}
```

Similar approach can be seen in this [article](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html).

Comment: Thank You. I understand now. I was doing the old school way. That article helps.

Comment: why should you subscribe to the route params instead of using snapshot? Isn't the only benefit to subscribing to the parameters in the scenario where you can navigate to multiple blog pages from individual blog pages? For instance, if the only way to navigate any blog page is from a list of blog page ids, then the blog page itself has no need for a subscription, right?

Comment: @NeilS. You're absolutely right. The subscribe is more beneficial when we've to jump on the active component again with different route parameters. 
We can also use the snapshot as you're suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of object creation angular does not have your `params`.

So you need to use it on either `ngOnInit` to assign it to a variable.

Or if you really want this code in constructor then use observable as follows

```
@Component({...})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    const id: Observable<string> = route.params.map(p => p.id);
    const url: Observable<string> = route.url.map(segments => segments.join(''));
    // route.data includes both `data` and `resolve`
    const user = route.data.map(d => d.user);
  }
}
```

Though use of ActivatedRoute in constructor is not a good practice I belive.

Reference : 
[ActivatedRoute-interface](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html)

Comment: So isn't component gets initialized by angular via lazy loading??  So when I am going to a route, it will get initialized and the TS class constructor gets called  OR angular loads the whole module in once ??  I Will check your observable solution today.

Comment: @user2225263 Lazy loading is a different concept than the lifecycle hooks. 
First, your component is initiated (Angular creates a new instance of your component using the constructor). Then the components loads into navigation (the routing happens), and then the other lifecycle hooks are triggered such as `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Ahh..ok..I see. Thanks Partha for your help. Appreciated.